# Why does my activerecord form lose the data? Yii2 framework

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I am starting with Yii framework, and it is my first framework... to the point:

I have a form to a CMS to enter a new blog post, an article. I also created a debug view to see the data being passed before I save it in the database, the thing is that when I use the form 2 of the fields dont pass any data to the debug view... I hope that more experienced people might help see what I am doing wrong here.

my code:

-Form view(new.php)

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'Title') ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'PublicationDate')->input('date') ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'Content')->textarea(['rows' => 5]) ?>

  <?= $form->field($model, 'tags') ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <?= Html::submitInput('Submint', ['class' => 'btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

Article model(Article.php):

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Article extends ActiveRecord{

  public $tags;

  public static function tableName()
  {
    return 'Article';
  }

  public function rules()
  {
    return[
      [['Title', 'Content'], 'required'],
    ];
  }
}
```

debug view:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>
<p>You have entered the following information:</p>

<ul>
  <li><label>Title</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->Title) ?></li>
  <li><label>PublicationDate</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->PublicationDate) ?></li>
  <li><label>Content</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->Content) ?></li>
  <li><label>tags</label>: <?= Html::encode($model->tags) ?></li>
</ul>
```

thank you in advance for you time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only *safe* attributes can receive user input. An attribute is considered *safe* when there is at least one validator defined for that attribute in `rules()`. If you simply want to declare an attribute as safe without doing any further validation, you can use the "safe" validator, like this:

```
public function rules()
{
return[
  [['Title', 'Content'], 'required'],
  [['PublicationDate', 'tags'], 'safe'],
];
}
```

Check http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked, and now I have some material to read thx once again :)